# How can I get a value from a named action into localStorage

Tags: sveltekit, svelte-3

I have a basic login form that triggers a named action on submit.  The code in the +page.server.js file is fetching a bearer token from a web API, which is working fine.  I'm currently writing the token value to a cookie, but I'd like to pass it back to the page to store in localStorage instead.

At one point I had it passing the value back, and displaying it to the page in an {#if} block.  But since the action triggers a page refresh, I'm not sure how to pass the value back in a way that I can then write it to localStorage.

I'm just learning Svelte, so I don't quite understand the flow of things yet.  Can I call a function in the page script, that would then call the named action, which would then return a value back to the function?  Or is there some easy thing I'm missing?

I tried moving the fetch into the page script, but I was getting a cross origin error. So I don't think that's a solution.

Basically I need to pass a username and password to a web API endpoint, then store the returned token so I can make subsequent calls to the web API.  I just have no idea how to do it properly.

Sorry for the long post, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Form actions are supposed to be used with the [`enhance` action](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/form-actions#progressive-enhancement-use-enhance), this action also allows you to add a callback which is executed with the result of the form action from the server (see docs for syntax). This callback can be used to store the result in `localStorage` or elsewhere.

Note that this approach does break fallback compatibility if JS is not available unlike using a cookie, in which case the form will cause a full reload and the credentials are stored.